# Unable to play any music in EMMS

Tags: emms

Running Emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

I installed EMMS from the package archive.

Added:

```
(require 'emms-setup)
(emms-standard)
(emms-default-players)
```

to my `init.el` as suggested [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/quickstart.html).

On restarting Emacs, it produces an error:

> Symbol's value as variable is void: `emms-playlist-mode-map`

So, something is wrong. What is it? How do I get EMMS to work?

Comment: I've had this same problem with EMMS, I eventually narrowed it down to `evil-collection`. Are you using `evil-collection` by chance? Try disabling it and see if the problem persists. Sorry but I never found a real solution to it, since I moved away from evil bindings by the time I came back around to EMMS.